# I want to do a search in real time of objects with Regex in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do the same of this following logic

```
// Create a pattern for a word that starts with letter "M"  
string pattern = @"\b[M]\w+";  
// Create a Regex  
Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
```

But I need the inside of the pattern to be a variable, for example

```
string search //I recieve this as a parameter
string pattern = @"\b[search]\w+";
```

How do I do this exactly?

Comment: String concatenation.

Comment: when I do a concatenation I recieve an error `string pattern = @"\b["+ search+"]\w+";`.

Comment: @d0rito What error do you get? You may need another `@`:  `string pattern = @"\b["+ search+@"]\w+";`

Comment: Or use string interpolation: `string pattern = $@"\b[{search}]\w+";`